# Warning: ‘cdecl’ attribute ignored [-Wattributes]

Tags: g++, c++, linux

Собираю примеры сторонней библиотеки под линукс, компилятор g++. Получаю предупреждение
warning: ‘cdecl’ attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
Что это означает и как это исправить?

Comment: Можно пример кода где пишет ворнинг?

Comment: Под какую платформу компилите?

Answer (score 1):

Это значит, что g++ проигнорировал объявление `cdecl` (сюрприз! но именно это означают слова "‘cdecl’ attribute ignored"). Ничего страшного в этом нет, значит, в вашем случае по умолчанию и так calling convention - `cdecl`.